# Order by values in an Excel chart

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find a simple way, inside an Excel chart, to order by values descending.  The largest value would appear at the far left in the chart, with all subsequent values, moving to the right, decreasing in value.  I'd like to do this without having to modify any of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using a pivot table and chart. This will not affect the original data.

[image: Pivottable & Chart]

Answer (score -1):

The problem with "I'd like to do this without having to modify any of the data" is that excel is not set up to do that. The chart is making assumptions, here is an example. In Cell A1 we have 1. in A2 we have 2 and on up to A20 = 20. If you chart this using a line chart, you will get a positive curve going from 1 to 20 BECAUSE the data was sorted from least to greatest. If you want the line to have a specific curve you have to SORT your data in a way that will force that curve. You do not have to edit the data, per se, but do have to sort it. If you can provide more specific information on what you are charting I'd be glad to see if I can help.